# Inserting text into iframe form field & submit

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, insert, submit

Okay so we have a star rating system on profiles that are embedded as a iframe, unsafe as its exposing database tables etc, but that is coming. Now we want to insert a rating value into a hidden field in a form inside that iframe from 1-5, and submit automatically. How can we achieve this? Several online examples do not work.

Inside iframe:

```
<form action="submit_rating.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="1" id="rate1" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" name="2" id="rate2" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" name="3" id="rate3" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" name="4" id="rate4" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" name="5" id="rate5" maxlength="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Rate" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://domain.com/submit_rating.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="10" width="25" name="frame"></iframe>
```

Rating links:

```
<a href="howtoinsert?">1</a>
<a href="howtoinsert?">2</a>
<a href="howtoinsert?">3</a>
<a href="howtoinsert?">4</a>
<a href="howtoinsert?">5</a>
```

Thank you. Like I said, all other examples were garbage and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (using jquery):

Rating site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function setRating(rating) {
        var frame = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
        $(frame).find('#rate'+rating).val('1');
        $(frame).find('form').submit();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="frame.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="10" width="25" name="frame"></iframe>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(1)">1</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(2)">2</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(3)">3</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(4)">4</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(5)">5</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Frame content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="submit_rating.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="1" id="rate1" maxlength="1">
      <input type="text" name="2" id="rate2" maxlength="1">
      <input type="text" name="3" id="rate3" maxlength="1">
      <input type="text" name="4" id="rate4" maxlength="1">
      <input type="text" name="5" id="rate5" maxlength="1">
      <input type="submit" value="Rate" style="display:none;" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

But an better way would be using ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function setRating(rating) {
        $.post('submit_rating.php', {
          rating: rating
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(1)">1</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(2)">2</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(3)">3</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(4)">4</a>
    <a href="javascript:setRating(5)">5</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now if I want to just insert a custom value, how to do this? $(frame).find('#about_me'+rating).val('1'); by a example custom input name. thank you